# Memory usage stays high after compilation jobs

Tags: memory, top

I am operating a small Linux VM with 1Gb of RAM.
It is a fairly typical LAMP setup which takes about 16% of memory on normal usage
I used the box to compile stuff yesterday, the memory went up to 60% and didn't drop back.
A memory sorted "top" doesn't show anything else than Mysql and Apache:

```
top - 09:41:33 up 4 days,  6:41,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  41 total,   1 running,  40 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1048576 total,   640072 used,   408504 free,        0 buffers
KiB Swap:   131072 total,        0 used,   131072 free,   533872 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2042 mysql     20   0  385m  41m 7324 S   0.0  4.1   9:25.35 mysqld
 1680 bind      20   0  117m  21m 2468 S   0.0  2.1   0:03.07 named
 2155 root      20   0  191m  10m 4988 S   0.0  1.1   1:07.43 apache2
12507 www-data  20   0  192m 9740 3032 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.50 apache2
12505 www-data  20   0  192m 9728 3020 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.19 apache2
12481 www-data  20   0  192m 9652 2940 S   0.0  0.9   0:01.47 apache2
12508 www-data  20   0  192m 9648 2940 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.73 apache2
12499 www-data  20   0  192m 9640 2932 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.24 apache2
12509 www-data  20   0  192m 9636 2928 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.26 apache2
12564 www-data  20   0  192m 9624 2924 S   0.0  0.9   0:01.07 apache2
12563 www-data  20   0  192m 9600 2928 S   0.0  0.9   0:00.33 apache2
14624 www-data  20   0  191m 7492 1296 S   0.0  0.7   0:00.30 apache2
14629 www-data  20   0  191m 7352 1248 S   0.0  0.7   0:00.24 apache2
```

Where did the missing 400Megs go?
Is this something that I should worry about or just wait for my scheduled weekly reboot?

For clarity, the "stuff" was Google Protocol Buffer which doesn't use any daemon.

Comment: Read [Linux ate my RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). Remember, free memory is wasted memory.

Comment: @Gilles Wow, a guy actually created a website dedicated to this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “missing” memory is serving as cache (mentioned in the `top` output at the end of the line that starts with the swap). You can use `free` to see this in a different form:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1048576     640072     408504          0          0     533872
-/+ buffers/cache:    106200      942376
Swap:       131072          0     131072
```

Comment: How do you read the second line?

Comment: That is `used - (buffers + cache)` and `free + (buffers + cached)`. Giving the values: `12547216 - (724568 + 6654748) = 5167900` resp. `3784708 + (724568 + 6654748) = 11164024`

Comment: @MonoThreaded Those values were for values in my [original answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/3d5bbee8-bcd7-47c9-8958-1a40549c72dc/view-source), not the yours that Gilles substituted, and which showed me that the cache information is displayed by `top` as well.